# Boolean failing to return the correct value

Tags: java

I have four classes Customer, Store and Item and Online.

I am using 'LinkedList' to move around classes.

I added items at the Customer class.

When I want to check whether the item under exists or not under Online class.

Because you cannot check at the Customer.

I use the hasItem().It's failing constantly.

When I say that, I mean even though I type "001A:GTA", the item is store in the data and it's not working.
it keep returning null.

Can someone explain to me?
I really appreciate it. I am a complete begineer.

Item Class

```
public class Item {
    private String code;
    private String name;
    public Item(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean hasItem(String code, String name){
      return code.equals(this.code) && name.equals(this.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " : " + code;
    }

}
```

Store class

```
    public class Store {
    private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();

    public Store(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void addItem(String code, String name){
          items.add(new Item(this, code, name);
       }

    public LinkedList<Item> viewItem(){
           for(int j = 0 ; j < items.size(); j++)
               System.out.println(items.get(j))
           return null; 
    }
}
```

Customer

```
   public class Customer {
    private LinkedList<Store> stores = new LinkedList<Store>();

    public Customer() {
        stores.add(new Store("Game", "1"));
        stores.add(new Store("Grocery", "2"));

        stores.get(0).addItem("001A", "GTA");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001B", "GOD OF WARS");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001C", "THE LAST OF US");

        stores.get(1).addItem("002A", "Sandwich");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002B", "Cup Noodle");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002C", "Ice Cream");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Customer().view();
    }

    public void view() {
        System.out.println(stores.get(0).viewItem());
    }

}
```

Online Class

```
class Online{
    private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
    private String name ;
    private String number;
    public Online(String name, String number){
       this.name = name;
       this.number = number;
    }

   public static void main(String args[]){
          new Customer(“John”, “012”).view();
    }

   private void view(){
      Item item = item(“001A:GTA”);
      if(item != null)
         System.out.println(“Found”);
      else
        System.out.println(“Not found”):
   }
    public Item item(String item){
      String[] temp = item.split(":");
      String code = temp[0];
      String name = temp[1];
      for(Item item: items)
          if(item.hasItem(code, name))
             return item;
      return null;
    } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Your Item class should not have a method named `hasItem()`. An item does not *have* an item. The `Store` class should have that method.

Comment: but the store is not connected to 'Online'

Comment: You seem to ask many questions about the same project involving `Customer`, `Store`, and `Item`. I think you should study [the basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Comment: Should your `hasItem` be called `equalTo`? And I think it should be referring to `contentEquals`, not `equals`.

Comment: Not @Jeff Holt.

Comment: Yeah, `hasItem` could be `isItem` … is _this_ item the same as _that_ item (bad name though, it could mean "is this an Item"), but that's really the job of the standard `.equals()` method. I wouldn't introduce "equalTo" or "contentEquals" which, to me, just confuse the meaning of _equals_.

Comment: @ratRedTears as "a complete beginner" I really want to give you more advice on the relationships among your classes, but this isn't the forum for that. One thing to think about though — is it the job of the `Customer` to add items to the `Store`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Override [Object::equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Objects;

class Item {
    private String code, name;

    public Item(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " : " + code;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, code);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Item item = (Item) obj;
        return name.equals(item.name) && code.equals(item.code);
    }
}

class Store {
    private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
    private String name, number;

    public Store(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void addItem(String code, String name) {
        items.add(new Item(code, name));
    }

    public LinkedList<Item> findItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Item item : items) {
            sb.append(item.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void viewStore() {
        System.out.println(name + " " + number);
    }

    /**
     * Searches the item in the store using the search string
     * 
     * @param The string combining the code and name in the format "code:name:"
     * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
     */
    public Item findItem(String strItem) {
        String[] data = strItem.split(":");
        if (data.length < 2) {
            return null;
        }

        Item searchItem = new Item(data[0], data[1]);

        for (Item item : items) {
            if (item.equals(searchItem)) {
                return item;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Searches the item in the store using the name of the item
     * 
     * @param The name of the item
     * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
     */
    public Item findItemByName(String itemName) {
        for (Item item : items) {
            if (item.getName().equals(itemName)) {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Customer {
    private LinkedList<Store> stores = new LinkedList<Store>();

    public Customer() {
        stores.add(new Store("Game", "1"));
        stores.add(new Store("Grocery", "2"));

        stores.get(0).addItem("001A", "GTA");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001B", "GOD OF WARS");
        stores.get(0).addItem("001C", "THE LAST OF US");

        stores.get(1).addItem("002A", "Sandwich");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002B", "Cup Noodle");
        stores.get(1).addItem("002C", "Ice Cream");
    }

    public LinkedList<Store> getStores() {
        return stores;
    }

    public void viewStore() {
        for (Store store : stores)
            store.viewStore();
    }

    public void viewItems() {
        for (Store store : stores) {
            for (Item item : store.findItems()) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Searches the item in all the stores related to the customer using the search
     * string
     * 
     * @param The string combining the code and name in the format "code:name:"
     * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
     */
    public Item findItem(String strItem) {
        String[] data = strItem.split(":");
        if (data.length < 2) {
            return null;
        }

        Item searchItem = new Item(data[0], data[1]);

        for (Store store : stores) {
            for (Item item : store.findItems()) {
                if (item.equals(searchItem)) {
                    return item;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Searches the item in all the stores related to the customer using the name of
     * the item
     * 
     * @param The name of the item
     * @return Returns the matching Item. If the item is not found, null is returned
     */
    public Item findItemByName(String itemName) {
        for (Store store : stores) {
            for (Item item : store.findItems()) {
                if (item.getName().equals(itemName)) {
                    return item;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class Online {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item item;
        String strItem, itemName;
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        // Test searching the item using the search string in a particular store e.g.
        // first store of customer
        Store store = customer.getStores().get(0);
        System.out.println("Searching item using search string in store, " + store.getName());

        strItem = "001A:GTA";
        item = store.findItem(strItem);
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found -> " + strItem);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
        }

        strItem = "002A:Sandwich";
        item = store.findItem(strItem);
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found -> " + strItem);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
        }

        System.out.println();

        // Test searching the item using the search string in all the stores related to
        // the customer
        System.out.println("Searching item using search string in all the stores related to the customer");
        strItem = "001A:GTA";
        item = customer.findItem(strItem);
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found -> " + strItem);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
        }

        strItem = "002A:Sandwich";
        item = customer.findItem(strItem);
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found -> " + strItem);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
        }

        strItem = "ABC:XYZ";
        item = customer.findItem(strItem);
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found -> " + strItem);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
        }

        System.out.println();

        // Test searching the item using name of the item in a particular store e.g.
        // first store of customer
        store = customer.getStores().get(0);
        System.out.println("Searching item using name of the item in store, " + store.getName());

        itemName = "GTA";
        item = store.findItemByName(itemName);
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found -> " + strItem);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
        }

        itemName = "Sandwich";
        item = store.findItemByName(itemName);
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found -> " + itemName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
        }

        System.out.println();

        // Test searching the item using the name of the item in all the stores related
        // to the customer
        System.out.println("Searching item  using name of the item in all the stores related to the customer");
        itemName = "GTA";
        item = customer.findItemByName(itemName);
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found -> " + itemName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
        }

        itemName = "Sandwich";
        item = customer.findItemByName(itemName);
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found -> " + itemName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
        }

        itemName = "XYZ";
        item = customer.findItemByName(itemName);
        if (item == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found -> " + itemName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found -> " + item);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Searching item using search string in store, Game
Found -> GTA : 001A
Not found -> 002A:Sandwich

Searching item using search string in all the stores related to the customer
Found -> GTA : 001A
Found -> Sandwich : 002A
Not found -> ABC:XYZ

Searching item using name of the item in store, Game
Found -> GTA : 001A
Not found -> Sandwich

Searching item  using name of the item in all the stores related to the customer
Found -> GTA : 001A
Found -> Sandwich : 002A
Not found -> XYZ
```

Note that it doesn't sound good for the class, `Item` to have a method called, `hasItem`. It gives an impression as if class, `Item` is a container class. Also, it is always a recommended practice to override `Object::equals` and `Object::hashCode` in a class. It makes your code clean (as you can see in the code given above) and helps you write logic in an easy manner; especially when you are dealing with collections.

Comment: when I just type GTA, I get array index out of bound execution. Should I make it null and ignore it @Arvind.

Comment: You need to check the size of the resulting array (resulted from split) before trying to access an element from it. I've already done it as `public Item getItem(String strItem) {
        String[] data = strItem.split(":");
        if (data.length < 2) {
            return null;
        }

        Item searchItem = new Item(data[0], data[1]);//...}` . You can see that I have checked `if (data.length < 2)`.  You should always do such checks. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: oh sorry I forget to explain what I want to do. If strTerm is just 'GTA', I want to automatically outputted the items they have.

Comment: Do you mean you want to search item just by name? If yes, the implementation needs to be changed. I'll do it and post it as an update.

Comment: I want to search by name and also (name and number). if the user only input just name, I want to ignore the number and automatically return the item that exists with the name and number.

Comment: I've defined two functions, `findItem` and `findItemByName`. If the user enters the search string (code:name), you need to call `findItem` and if the user enters the name of the item, you need to call `findItemByName`.

Comment: Thanks you so much @Arvind

Comment: For information, is there any way equals two items without @Override Objects::equal

Comment: This is the standard way and I recommend you stick to the standard. If you wish, you can post a separate question specific to this requirement, `is there any way equals two items without @Override Objects::equal`. However, I do not recommend it as people may downvote the question because everyone recommends to stick to the standard. If you will be lucky, you will get answer(s) and even upvote for the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212527/discussion-between-ratredtears-and-arvind-kumar-avinash).

Answer (score 1):

you are searching for "001:GTA" but in the example you stored the item "001A:GTA"

Answer (score 0):

hasItem is a function of the class Item.  But you appear to be calling it against the LIST of items

```
 if(items.hasItem(code, name))
```

I think that should be

```
 if(item.hasItem(code, name))
```